# React useState variable resets to True when I access it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I'm having a very strange issue where my boolean useState variable (allowClickUpload) is True when I already set it to False. You may be thinking I am accessing it too soon and it's an async operation, but I can wait up to 10 full minutes later and then trigger the console log and it's always True.

In the below code I am console logging any change to allowClickUpload using a useEffect. The output is as expected... True at first because that's my initial value, and then once I upload a file it becomes false. Good so far. Then I click the screen once more and output the value and it's True without my useEffect being triggered. How is this possible? It's as if there are more than 1 instance or something. I really have no idea.

Please see the code below. It's a canvas area which allows users to drag/drop an image onto it. I've removed all the "extra" code to leave just a bare bones implementation which still causes the issue. Any help is appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const CanvasPanel = () => {
  const [allowClickUpload, setAllowClickUpload] = useState(true);
  const [img, setImg] = useState(document.createElement("img"));
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [context, setContext] = useState({});
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    // LOG every change to allowClickUpload
    console.log("allowClickUpload " + allowClickUpload);
  }, [allowClickUpload]);

  const clearCanvas = () => {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  };

  const centerImage = () => {
    var windowWidth = canvas.width;
    var windowHeight = canvas.height;
    var imgWidth = img.width;
    var imgHeight = img.height;

    var left, top;

    if (imgWidth >= windowWidth) {
      left = 0;
    } else {
      left = (windowWidth - imgWidth) / 2;
    }

    if (imgHeight >= windowHeight) {
      top = 0;
    } else {
      top = (windowHeight - imgHeight) / 2;
    }

    context.drawImage(img, left, top, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    setData(context.getImageData(left, top, imgWidth, imgHeight).data);
  };

  const processDrop = (file) => {
    if (file.type === "image/png" || file.type === "image/jpeg") {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (evt) {
        img.src = evt.target.result;
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      setAllowClickUpload(false);
    }
  };

  const handleStopEvent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
      processDrop(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
      e.dataTransfer.clearData();
    }
  };

  const handleImageLoad = () => {
    clearCanvas();
    centerImage();
  };

  const handlePickFile = (e) => {
    processDrop(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleMouseDown = () => {
    // allowClickUpload is always True here even though the useEffect shows it is false
    console.log("allowClickUpload " + allowClickUpload);
    if (allowClickUpload) {
      document.getElementById("fileUpload").click();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("draganddrop-wrapper");
    const { width, height } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    canvas.addEventListener("dragenter", handleStopEvent);
    canvas.addEventListener("dragleave", handleStopEvent);
    canvas.addEventListener("dragover", handleStopEvent);
    canvas.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);

    window.addEventListener("drop", handleStopEvent);
    window.addEventListener("dragover", handleStopEvent);

    img.addEventListener("load", handleImageLoad);

    setCanvas(canvas);
    setContext(canvas.getContext("2d"));

    return () => {
      canvas.removeEventListener("dragenter", handleStopEvent);
      canvas.removeEventListener("dragleave", handleStopEvent);
      canvas.removeEventListener("dragover", handleStopEvent);
      canvas.removeEventListener("drop", handleDrop);
      canvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);

      window.removeEventListener("drop", handleStopEvent);
      window.removeEventListener("dragover", handleStopEvent);

      img.removeEventListener("load", handleImageLoad);
    };
  }, [context]);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <canvas id="draganddrop-wrapper"></canvas>
      <input
        type="file"
        className="hidden"
        id="fileUpload"
        onChange={(e) => handlePickFile(e)}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  height: calc(100vh - 160px);
  flex: 1;
  background: var(--neutral-color);
  border: 1px solid var(--dark-text-color);
  color: var(--dark-text-color);
  margin: 0;
  canvas {
    width: calc(100vw - 310px);
    height: calc(100vh - 160px);
    image-rendering: pixelated;
  }
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export default CanvasPanel;
```

Here's the output from my console when running. First output is from useEffect showing true on load. Next is false from me actually setting it to false. Next is True which is coming from handleMouseDown(). Comments in code as well.

[image: console_output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `context` state can't properly update, as it is initialized as an empty object, and the `useEffect` only updates on changes to `context`, and the only place `setContext` is used is in the `useEffect`, so it is never triggered.

On a side note, in React you would normally add event listeners directly to the element (using `onClick`, or `onDragEnter` etc) rather than using `addEventListener` and getting elements by id, e.g.:

```
<canvas  
    onDrop={e => handleDrop(e)}
    onDragOver={e => handleDragOver(e)}
    onDragEnter={e => handleDragEnter(e)}
    onDragLeave={e => handleDragLeave(e)}>
</canvas>
```

Take a look at this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/02/html-drag-drop-api-react/

Comment: Good point about the events. I pulled some of this code together from an older Vue project and the rest from a simple drag/drop component I wrote for something else. What other dependencies would I add to get this working as expected? Even after reading your comment I'm unsure. <-- heading to read that link now which may answer my question.

Comment: Ha - Moving all of my events within the canvas solved the bug. Cheers!

Comment: From what I can tell, the way you are setting 'context' is only by using setContext within the useEffect. In the useEffect, you have [context] at the end, and this is what React is listening for changes on. As you are only running the useEffect when 'context' changes, and only setting context within the useEffect, you aren't able to properly update the state.

Answer (score 2):

You've only added *context* as a dependency to your useEffect hook which sets up your event listeners. Even though your component is rerendering, and the function is updated, the event listener is still referencing the original function in which your state was true.

Comment: That's a good point, would I add the event listeners as dependencies? Just saying that sounds weird, but I'm not sure what other dependencies to add to get the events to work with the right data.

Comment: You would need to add the functions that these event listeners depends on to your dependencies array. But I agree withwhat @srosser2 wrote, it is definitely a better approach to add the directly to the element, rather than using an useEffect hook.